# Why does 'git diff branch1 branch2' not work from the repo root?

Tags: git

I can see the expected output from 'git diff branch1 branch2' when I run it from any other folder than the repos root. I f I run this command from the root I get the following error

*fatal: ambiguous argument 'capture': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'*

Why does this not work from the root?

Comment: Do you have both a branch and a file named `capture`?

Comment: As the error message explains, there is a simple way to disambiguate the meaning of any argument Git cannot handle: put an argument consisting of two dashes (`--`) between the branch names and file names. If your command line does not contain any file name this means it should end with `--`.

Comment: Good point @axiac! I added this to below answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you might have both a file and a branch or tag sharing the same name. You can specify the branches separated by `..` instead of space to disambiguate. In the context of `git diff`, `..` and space mean the same thing.

So instead of:

```
git diff branch1 branch2
```

Do:

```
git diff branch1..branch2
```

More information on this syntax is available at [man gitrevisions](https://gitirc.eu/gitrevisions.html).

You can also use the first syntax and end with `--` to indicate that there are no paths before it:

```
git diff branch1 branch2 --
```

---

To specify a filename without it being interpreted as a branch name, use the path separator `--` as suggested in the help message.

Example:

```
git diff branch1..branch2 -- file1
```

Comment: We had a folder and a branch named 'capture', I did not understand the error message and could find no 'digestible' info on what revisions versus paths are and when .. or -- comes into play. Thanks, I now know a bit more.